# Java class attribute name same as classname

Tags: java, scala, oop

I have Java class whose classname is same as one of its attribute's name.
Now I get error saying "encountered unrecoverable cycle resolving import" when trying to create object for that class in scala.

```
public class linkId extends org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase implements org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord {
.
.
.
.
.
public linkId(java.lang.String linkId, java.lang.String linkIdScheme) {
    this.linkId = linkId;
    this.linkIdScheme = linkIdScheme;
  }
.
.
.
.
}
```

> [ERROR] [Error]
>   /Users/dnamburi/.../src/generated/avro/com/rbccm/TradeMessage/linkId.java:15:
>   **encountered unrecoverable cycle resolving import**. Note: this is often
>   due in part to a class depending on a definition nested within its
>   companion. If applicable, you may wish to try moving some members into
>   another object.

Comment: The error message relates to one or more `import` statements.  You have presented none, so we have no way to know what the problem is (simply having a field with the same name as its class is not sufficient).  Please present a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Also, however, consider adhering to standard Java naming conventions, by giving classes names with initial capital letters, and members names with initial lowercase letters.  This makes your code easier to read, and it might (maybe) resolve your problem, too.